# Regex to accept numbers and/or number range separated by commas, but between range 1-64

Tags: regex, numbers, expression

I need to validate a string entered by user.
The string should allow numbers or ranges, separated by comma. The numbers must be between 1 and 64.

```
Sample: 1,8,7-9,10-12,20-45
```

A space is allowed before and after a comma or '-'.

Comment: It seems to me that regex is not the best way to approach this issue. I would split the string on commas first, then check to see if what is inside is a # or range. If the latter, split on the hyphen and validate that the first part of the range is less than the last.

Comment: Checking numeric values with regular expressions is like stirring paint with a hammer.  You can do it, but that's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,

```
^(?:6[0-4]|[1-5]\d|[1-9])(?: *- *(?:6[0-4]|[1-5]\d|[1-9]))?(?: *, *(?:6[0-4]|[1-5]\d|[1-9])(?: *- *(?:6[0-4]|[1-5]\d|[1-9]))?)*$
```

I used `<space>*` instead of `\s*` because `\s` matches newline characters also. Use `\s` instead of a space, if you have no problem about newline character. Use `\s?` instead of `<space>*`, if you want to allow an optional space not zero or more spaces.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sM5jU3/2)

Comment: That is a very neat demo tool

Comment: @AvinashRaj Its almost perfect except that it doesnt validate a single number, or single range, e.g say just "7" or just "1-7".

Comment: i alreday told that you need to change the last `+` to `*`, so that it accepts the sing;e number.

Comment: Missed that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This should match an integer between 1-64.

```
([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-4])
```

This should accept ranges as well.

```
([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-4])(-([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-4]))?
```

To match one or more in a single line.

```
^(([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-4])(-([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-4]))?\s*($|,\s*))+$
```

Comment: But how to tell that it's a range, e.g., 20-45 and not 64-45? One can only hope there are no such values!

Comment: I would not use regex to validate that. It's trivial to write a function to check that in any programming language. I can't think of a reasonable way of doing it with a regular expression.

Comment: Brilliant and concise. But it accepts a comma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's going to be gross. I don't think there's a simple answer because regex matches strings, not numbers. as it turns out, a number between 0 and 64 looks something like this

```
[1-6]?[0-9]
```

some maybe with a range incorporated (but not spaces or commas)

```
[1-6]?[0-9](\-[1-6]?[0-9])?
```

EDIT

Here I manually entered spaces and commas with a "?" directly after (appears once or not at all), if you'll allow multiple space, change the relevant "?" to "*" I can't 100% promise this will work, but constructing it piece by piece, I believe it will work.

```
\([1-6]?[0-9]\( ?\- ?[1-6]?[0-9]\)? ?,? ?\)+
```

I will try to update if I cook up something better.

EDIT2

My old pattern would match 0 if I had written in grouping correctly. Let's try this:

```
((([1-5]?[0-9])|(6[0-4])((\s?\-\s?([1-5]?[0-9])|(6[0-4]))?)(\s?,\s?)?)+
```

Happy Coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: `([1-5]?[0-9])|(6[0-4])`